# error en bucle for y condicionante if

Tags: python, bucle-for, condiciones

Soy un entusiasta de la porgramacion con algunos conocimientos sobre el tema, les ruego me disculpen,me queda mucho por aprender, tengo este codigo donde consulto el saldo de mi cuenta y los recibo en forma de lista e imprimo la moneda y el total que tengo l lado de ella, pero me imprimo todos los valores aunque tengo 0, buscaba la forma de que ignorara los valores en 0 y solo imprimiera los demas y recibo ese error, me podrian ayudar? muchisimas gracias por adelantado

mi variable total me estaria devolviendo esto:
['18.02787287', '0.00003897', '0.00003067', '0.00002044', '0.0000006', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']

de ahi que desee que solo me imprima los diferentes a 0

```
coin=[b['currency'] for b in balances]
total=[b['available'] for b in balances]

for i, j in zip(coin, total):
    if j>=1:
        print('en su cuenta de trade tiene en',i,':', j)
    else:
        continue
```

error:
'>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Buen día, es posible que tu variable `total` esté recibiendo `strings` (No agregaste la información que tiene balances así que solo puedo suponer) y luego en la línea `if j>=1` estarías comparando un `string` con un `int` (El valor 1).

Comment: ['18.02787287', '0.00003897', '0.00003067', '0.00002044', '0.0000006', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'] esto me devuelve mi variable total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema está porque tu variable `total` tiene `string`  los identificas porque cada número tiene comillas, por ejemplo `'0'`. Por lo tanto cuando intentas comparar `j>=1` te dice que no puedes comparar un `string` con el valor `1` que es un `int`

Puedes convertir los `string` a enteros (`int`) o en tu caso necesitarías `float` porque tienen decimales

Para hacerlo agrega `float(j)` en tu `if`, de esta forma `if float(j)>=1:`

```
coin=[b['currency'] for b in balances]
total=[b['available'] for b in balances]

for i, j in zip(coin, total):
    if float(j)>=1:
        print('en su cuenta de trade tiene en',i,':', j)
    else:
        continue
```

Aunque si comparas solo que sea mayor o igual a 1 entonces estarías eliminando los valores que tienen decimales, como `0.0000006`

Comment: uyy, habia probado convertir con int pero no probe float,jejeje,  muchisimas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @Nigan, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Comment: disculpa, estaba tratand de dar manito arriba y no me dejaba, soy nuevo en esto, ya vi como aceptarla, gracias de nuevo por todo